# Source model "instagramconnect/source_instagram_user" not found for attribute "instagram_category_source_user"

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, error, eav

Any solution of following code then let me know it urgent.
I have also  remove `instagram_category_source_user` row form `env_attribute` table after getting this. but don’t fix it any solution.

Following is error log

```
a:5:{i:0;s:110:"Source model "instagramconnect/source_instagram_user" not found for attribute "instagram_category_source_user"";i:1;s:4101:"#0 /home/new/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "i...')
    #1 /home/new/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(203): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
    #2 /home/new/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Attributes.php(113): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset))
    #3 /home/new/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
    #4 /home/new/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
    #5 /home/new/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php(140): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
    #6 /home/new/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
    #7 /home/new/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
    #8 /home/new/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Edit/Form.php(55): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'tabs')
    #9 /home/new/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form->_prepareLayout()
    #10 /home/new/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
    #11 /home/new/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php(82): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...')
    #12 /home/new/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container->_prepareLayout()
    #13 /home/new/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
    #14 /home/new/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
    #15 /home/new/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
    #16 /home/new/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
    #17 /home/new/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
    #18 /home/new/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
    #19 /home/new/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
    #20 /home/new/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
    #21 /home/new/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(201): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
    #22 /home/new/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController->editAction()
    #23 /home/new/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
    #24 /home/new/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #25 /home/new/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #26 /home/new/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #27 /home/new/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #28 {main}";s:3:"url";s:77:"/index.php/admin/catalog_category/index/key/9351780785703cfd533745a8e8729204/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gather you removed a module, but it looks like its attributes are still in tables.

From the trace, looks like you are attempting to load the category manager.
If so, looks like you got a stale attribute in the table :

catalog_eav_attribute

Check that table, for 'instagram_category_source_user', in the field frontend_input_renderer, and remove it.

Comment: Ok let me check that

Comment: Thanks for faster  reply it work me.  and more thing   i have also remove entry from "core_resource" table of modules